# Referencing Vuetify in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuetify.js

I have the following code which works fine.

```
<script>
export default {
 methods: {
   foo() {
     return this.$vuetify.theme.dark;
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

I have now switched over to TypeScript and changed it to look like this.

```
<script type="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';
@Component
export default class MyClass extends Vue {
  public foo(): boolean {
     return this.$vuetify.theme.dark;
  }
}
</script>
```

It is now complaining that "property $vuetify does not exist on my class", which makes sense because the definition of 'this' has changed context.

What do I need to do to resolve this and have it working as the same way the non-TypeScript version does?

Comment: It seems that vuetify types not installed, check your tsconfig.js for https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vue-cli-plugins/issues/112#issuecomment-562935079,

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I already had vuetify in the types section. I added the typeRoots section from that post but no luck.

Comment: Sad to hear it. So... may be the simplest way is to recreate project by vue cli with typescript, do `vue add vuetify` and copy template part.
it is difficult to check was the switch to typescript done correctly.